# Given a class file, how to detect it uses JNI or not?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, bytecode, .class-file, javap

I have some Java benchmarks with only class files.

I would like to find which benchmarks have JNI calls.

I thought maybe this can be done from the bytecode level with the help of `javap -c`, but not sure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers.

I found a simple way as below:

`java -verbose:jni -jar foo.jar`

Basically, it prints a trace message to the console showing the JNI methods.

Here is the details about this option from HotSpot : [ref](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbmtv)

Answer (score 7):

If you're allowed to load the class, you can use reflection:

```
Class<?> clazz = ...
List<Method> nativeMethods = new ArrayList<>();
for (Method m : clazz.getDelcaredMethods()) {
    if(Modifier.isNative(m.getModifiers())) {
        nativeMethods.add(m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear from original question if you want to find native (JNI) methods programmatically. With javap you can use something like this:

```
javap -private java.awt.image.BufferedImage | grep native
```

Comment: That might lead to false positives.

Comment: @Antimony How would it?

Comment: If one of the methods had 'native' in its name for instance.

Comment: @Antimony I think it would be fairly easy to see which methods were and were not. When you execute that line you get the entire signature of the method, and it would be pretty easy to spot the false positives. But if you follow EJP's advice, you won't get any.

Comment: Assuming of course the class files are unmodified Java. If they were obfuscated or not originally compiled from Java, then it's possible you might have a method named `native`. Then again, it's also possible for javap to just crash trying to parse the classfile. I suppose it's not a big worry unless you're doing RE.

Answer (score 0):

This works along the lines you've described:

```
javah  [options] <classes> -d <dir>
grep -r "JNIEXPORT" <dir>
```

Each line of output will identify a native method using its JNI export name.

However, this does not determine if the native method has been called or loaded by the JVM or even defined in a shared library. A native method only needs to be defined if it is called and even then its absence is a trappable error.